# JSON formatting + Calculated columns pic link fixes

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, json, image

I used to have a picture in some calculated columns that function as links based on some of the attributes of an item. We were told to use JSON formatting at that time, but apparently now it seems like JSON formatting is a half baked pie that really isn't working either. So my question is, does anyone have a good solution out there to achieve the same ends - which is to make a pictorial link, based on attributes of the values from an item, without full VS capabilities.

I did a quick search but that didn't yield much results, if someone can point me to the right place to look, that will be helpful.

Thanks!~

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the modern experience? If so, it sounds like a good candidate for column formatting: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting

Comment: No, I am not using modern experience. I don't think modern experience works with scripting, which cripples the current site. Don't really have the resources to move to a new platform at this time...

Comment: I used this approach and it did not work. Simply didn't do anything to the column in the current list view.